# Discord.js send file after embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Currently, my bot sends a file before the embed, but I want it the opposite way.
This is my discord.js v12 code:

```js
msg.send({embed: {
     "title": "Success",
     "description": `Successfully added ${args[1]}` + "\n Use `m!stock` to see it.",
     "color": "#22ba4a"
   }, files: [free]})
```

[image: Current]

Comment: Separate the call? Send embed and then follow up with the file, there's a call-back to know you sent the message so fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Message>.send()` is a promise, meaning that you can use `.then()` functions after your message is sent. For example, your code would look something like this:

```js
msg.send({
    embed: {
        "title": "Success",
        "description": `Successfully added ${args[1]}\nUse \`m!stock\` to see it.`,
        "color": "#22ba4a"
    },
}).then(() => {
    msg.send({
        files: [free]
    });
});
```

#### More on `Promises`

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

#### More on `.then()`

[Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)